# how to stop Javascript function execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My program has two buttons. One is for **execute** other program by using jquery load function. Whenever I click execute button, it runs some other program `abc.php` using load function for n times, with some time gap like k mins. These n and k will be filled with html inputs. Using jquery, will retrieve these and passing to that program file in url.

To call this function `setTimeout` was used.

Second one is for **cancel** execution.

Now my doubt is, suppose I want to stop that execution with cancel button. Is there any way to stop it ?

Comment: You should really give a code example of your JavaScript, but most likely you're talking about how to do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123237/how-to-stop-a-timer-function-from-running)

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802936/stop-all-active-ajax-requests-in-jquery)

Comment: Are you connecting to the PHP file ones at the time (re connect after other connection finishes) or all at the same time?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp OR http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_cleartimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set time for function:

```
timer = setTimeout(function(){$('#submenu').hide();},5000);
```

stop a function

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do this using **`boolean`** variable.

For example: Consider a method, perform logging.

```
fun () {
  console.log("prints");
}
```

I would change it has

```
fun (isExecute) {
  if (isExecute) {
   console.log("prints");
  }
}
```

<kbd>Run</kbd> `fun (true);`  <kbd>cancel</kbd> `fun (false);`

---

### Updates:

It seems you use `setTimeout()`, then it is too easy without above approach.

<kbd>Run</kbd> **`var inter = setTimeout(fun);`**  <kbd>cancel</kbd> **`clearTimeout(inter);`**

**FYI:** The reason for assigning to a variable **`inter`** *is then only you can clear this time interval.*